# TortoiseSVN - Cannot rename file

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I tried to rename an Excel file using TortoiseSVN 1.8 (Windows 7) but didn't realise I had left the file open in Excel at the time. The rename failed with Tortoise telling me the file was opened. However, when I try to rename with the file closed, I get error messages saying the file already exists. It doesn't! There is no other file related to this one in my working copy. It looks like Tortoise has tried to create the newly-named file, added it to SVN, realised it can't delete the old one and deleted the new, but hasn't removed the non-existent new file from SVN. What can I do about this? I tried Clean Up with the default settings but although it succeeded, it didn't help.

Comment: what is the output of  'svn status'?

Comment: I think "TortoiseSVN --> Clean up..." from the file explorer context menu on the working copy folder will do the trick here. It may clean up the unnecessary new file information created in repo information locally.

Comment: @RinoTom I already did, see the last line of my post. It didn't do anything. I've been in this situation before, where clean-up succeeds but does nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reminding me of the command line. I went to a command shell and did `svn st` on the folder, and saw the exclamation mark on the renamed file (i.e. file not found). So I did an `svn rm <new file>`, checked in, `svn rename <old file> <new file>` and checked in again - seems to have worked fine. Will need to be careful in future about renaming open files!